# Android: limit rotate animation fps

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an icon, and I want it to be rotate all the time. So far so good, only that I want to limit the frame to 12fps so that it will produce my expected effects. How can I do that?

```
   ImageView loadingCircle= (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loading_circle_image);    
   RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f * 360.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,   0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    rotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
    loadingCircle.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

Comment: you cannot do that, sorry

Comment: IF your animation is a bit fast then try increasing duration. You can't play with fps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control duration but not number of frames generated. If that's needed, then you can make these 12 frames yourself using software like GIMP or Photoshop, and by rotating your image by hand to get 12 separate frames. Then you use Animation Drawable ([docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)), create separate drawable XML for your animation and refer your separate frames from XML. Ensure you set `android:duration` for your frames correctly to have each of them shown per 12th part of second.